# Using JMS to put a Message in a MQ Queue And Consuming Message by SPLUNK

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq, mq, splunk

Im trying to put a message in a MQ Queue. Here is my source code:

```
        QueueConnection queueConn;
        QueueSession queueSession;
        QueueSender queueSender;

        queueConn = connectionFactory.getConnection();
        queueSession = queueConn.createQueueSession(false,
                Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        queueSender = queueSession.createSender(queueSession
                .createQueue(KEY_CONFIG_QUEUE_NAME));
        queueSender.setDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode.NON_PERSISTENT);

        TextMessage message = queueSession.createTextMessage(logBase);

        queueSender.send(message);
```

I don't have the source code from the queue consumer, that is the one who sends the messages to SPLUNK. But at SPLUNK console, I could realize that the message is composed by JMS HEADER + my text message (logBase).

Id like the messages without JMS Header. Could someone help me to understand where the problem is? Could be at consumer? Maybe a wrong or missing SPLUNK config??

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you cannot change the source code at the consumer, there is a way to administratively do this. You can change the queue definition so that these message properties are not given to the getting application.

```
ALTER QLOCAL(q-name) PROPCTL(NONE)
```

**Related Links**

- [PROPCTL queue options](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/?lang=en#!/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.mig.doc/q008230_.htm)

Comment: Hello morag. We are trying to change Splunk configs so that we can define de message format. Change the Queues configurations is not an option to us.

Comment: I am curious why changing queue manager config such as a queue definition isn't possible? For most environments it is much easier to change a queue def than an application.

Comment: Hello Morag, thanks for answering. Ins't possible because the queue is used by many other applications and we don't know exactly what impact this config could have considering this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

If you able and happy to change the producer, you could look into the Target Client property of the MQ JMS destination.

This informs the JMS client that the consuming application is not a JMS app so it removes the extra headers.

Comment: Unfortunately i cant.